# Showing menu overflow icon again

Tags: android, android-layout

I called `toolbar.removeAllViews()` in my code, it cleared everything in my action bar including my menu to overflow icon. But when I called `onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)` again in my app no menu overflow shows how do I fix this?

Comment: You should not be callind `onCreateOptionsMenu()` on yourself, that's a callback that framework should call.

Comment: But on my logcat (i.e log.i()) that I placed in the onCreateOptionsMenu(menu) that shows me the created menu. When ever I call the onCreateOptionsMenu(menu) it shows the on the log meaning the onCreateOptionsMenu(menu) actually runs. And I thought whenever that function is called the options menu gets created.

Comment: Instead of calling `oncreateOptionsMenu()` manually call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`.

Comment: @azizbekian what does that do?

Comment: @azizbekian what does that do?

Comment: See docs please.